# My Leyden jar is discharging very quickly?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, capacitance

First of all, I have made two Leyden jars and connecting them together to get 2.272 nanofarad, I am trying to charge it using a twelve volts charger. When I measure how many volts it has when charging, using a multimeter, it shows me twelve volts, but when I disconnect the charger, it drops to three then goes crazy, I understand that it's discharging, I want to know why? And where the charges are going?
I am trying to compare between it and an electrolytic capacitor except that it's not keeping the charge.

Comment: There could be any number of things wrong with it;  to answer this question, we'll almost certainly need more information about how the jars are constructed, how you're connecting them, etc.

Comment: I am using plastic bottles filled with water, and covered with foil, on top of it there is a nail. When measuring the capacity I am connecting one side of the multimeter with the nail, and the other with a thin cable connected to the foil. @MichaelSeifert

Comment: Whats the internal resistance of your multimeter?

Comment: The multimeter is actually a resistor and provides a discharge path. Are you using distilled water? If not, then impurities in the water form a discharge path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the capacitance is really only $2.2\,nF$, that's not a lot. With that little capacitance, you can no longer treat the multimeter as having an infinite input impedance.

The voltage across a capacitor of $C$ farads discharging through a resistance of $R$ ohms will decrease with time as
$$V(t)=V_0e^{-t/RC}\ \ .$$
So for example, if you're measuring the voltage across the $2.2\,nF$ capacitor with a multimeter with an input impedance of $10M\Omega$ (which is considered respectable), it will only take a tenth of a second for the voltage to drop from $12V$ all the way down to $0.13V$. My guess is that what's going wrong is simply that the Leyden jars are quickly discharging through the multimeter.